# populate dropdownlist with DBnames except system DBs

Tags: c#, if-statement, sqlconnection

I  need to connect to SQL db from C# windows application 
and populate a dropdown list from a connection to have all db from server in a dropdown except system DBs.

I have this code:

```
 using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=" + serverName + ";User Id=" + uName + ";Password=" + pass + ";"))
                {
                    thisConnection.Open();

                    // Assign it to dropdown menu
                    DataTable databases = thisConnection.GetSchema("Databases");
                    foreach (DataRow database in databases.Rows)
                     {
                         String databaseName = database.Field<String>("database_name");

                        //  MessageBox.Show(databaseName);
                          if (databaseName  == "master")
                          {

                          }
                        if (databaseName == "model")
                          {

                        }
                        if (databaseName == "tempdb")
                        {

                        }
                        if (databaseName == "msdb")
                        {

                        }
                        else
                          { //adding DBs names into dropdownlist  dd_ddase
                            dd_ddase.Items.Add(databaseName);
                        }


                    }
```

However it still returns system dbs in drop down, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @IamDOM I need just populate dropdown so I can build connection string to specific db

Comment: @IamDOM it is complete to server, I need to select all not system dbs into dropdown, next step depend on chosen db in dropdown i will create connection  specific db and get info on tables in that  db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler version based on database id.

```
foreach (DataRow database in databases.Rows)
{
    var id = database.Field<short>("dbid");
    var name = database.Field<string>("database_name");

    if (id > 4)
    {
        dd_ddase.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, It's useful for u

```
               foreach (DataRow database in databases.Rows)
                {
                    String databaseName = database.Field<String>("database_name");
                    //  MessageBox.Show(databaseName);
                    if (databaseName == "master" || databaseName == "model" || databaseName == "tempdb" || databaseName == "msdb")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(databaseName);
                    }    

                }
```